# mpdf is not displaying page number in roman numerals in lower case in version 7

Tags: mpdf

I am having trouble to display page number in roman numerals in lower case in version `7 of MPDF`. I am getting roman numerals in upper case only. I am using `php 6.5` and using the code as in the example

```
// Set a simple Footer including the page number
$mpdf->setFooter('{PAGENO}');

$mpdf->WriteHTML('Section 1');$mpdf->WriteHTML('');

// You could also do this using
// $mpdf->AddPage('','','','','on');

$mpdf->WriteHTML('Section 2 - No Footer');
$mpdf->WriteHTML('<pagebreak resetpagenum="1" pagenumstyle="i" suppress="off" />');
$mpdf->WriteHTML('Section 3 - Starting with page a');

$mpdf->Output();
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Looks like a bug. I'd recommend opening an issue on Github https://github.com/mpdf/mpdf/issues

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was indeed a bug, it is fixed now in a new [patch release v7.1.2](https://github.com/mpdf/mpdf/tree/v7.1.2).